# Permanently store, modify and load "config variables" in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to **change** and **load** permanently a set of variables in my application. Global configuration variables that will set my environment.

For what i have seen, i can create a config file and change it through a post form in my backoffice but it **won't be persistent**.

What is the best way to change and access "configuration data" without using a database and query it all the time?

Comment: have you tryed to use sessions? and on the construct function of the class, set the config file to use the session value?

Comment: either database or text/JSON files are your options. Database would be best.

Comment: why not use a database?

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter we can added any number of config variables for the site. Follow the step to add and retrieve the value of custom added config variable.

1. Define the config variables in config.php in `‘application/config’` folder

   `$config['config_variable1']    = 'Config value 1';`
2. To get these values in the view files located in `‘application/views’`

Refer this office link of CodeIgniter for further reference, [Config Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/config.html)